MACOS: cp command fails when using * to look up for all files with certain extension because of quotes?
The following command:
cp "/Users/my.name/Documents/GitHub/Folder/*.dylib" "/Users/my.name/Documents/GitHub/OtherFolder"

Throws the following:
No such file or directory
The following command:
cp "/Users/my.name/Documents/GitHub/Folder/theFile.dylib" "/Users/my.name/Documents/GitHub/OtherFolder"

Copy the file.
The following commands:
cd "/Users/my.name/Documents/GitHub/Folder/"
cp *.dylib "/Users/my.name/Documents/GitHub/OtherFolder"

This leads me to believe this is due to the presence of quotes "...". Same when using '...'. Why is that ? What can I do if the path contains spaces ?

In a unix shell (bash, zsh, etc.), you can quote any portion of the string (with double quotes or single quotes), you don't have to quote the entire string. e.g.
bll-g7:bll$ mkdir -p $HOME/'dq"'/"sq'"/stuff
bll-g7:bll$ ls -ld $HOME/'dq"'/"sq'"/stuff
drwxr-xr-x 2 bll bll 4096 Jun 10 08:33 /home/bll/dq"/sq'/stuff/

In the case of wild cards, you can do:
cp "/Users/my.name/Documents/folder with space/lib/"*.dylib \
   $HOME/somewhere/


ok but what is the logic about that ? Why can't wild cards be surrounded by quotes ?

When a wild card is quoted, the shell will not expand it, it preserves the character.   When you quote something, you want the actual value, not the expansion.
